# Is pyspark dataframe a pointer?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I read several dataframes from different locations and them union them. To do that, firstly I collect them in a list.

```py
from functools import reduce
# spark initialization
df_list = []

for path in paths:
    df = spark.table(path)
    df_list.append(df)

data = reduce(lambda x, y : x.union(y), df_list)
```

The question is when I read `df`, and append it to `df_list`, then on the next iteration of the loop do reassignment of `df`, does it change the value that already has been appended to the `df_list`? As far as I know, that could be the case for pointer variables.

Comment: Your list is stored on the driver. spark.table() would run on executors. Are you sure this runs, as expected in a distributed environment?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest refactoring to not use a list at all

```
df = spark.table(paths[0])

for path in paths[1:]:
    df = df.union(spark.table(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `union` You can pass list of paths to spark `load` function like below.

```
>>> paths = ['/tmp/data/a','/tmp/data/b','/tmp/data/c']
>>> df = spark.read.format('orc').load(paths)
>>> df.show(5, False)
+---+
|id |
+---+
|88 |
|89 |
|90 |
|91 |
|92 |
+---+
only showing top 5 rows
```

A list is necessary instead of a parent directory without a schema. Example:

```
scala> spark.read.format("orc").load("/tmp/data")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for ORC. It must be specified manually.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryCompilationErrors$.dataSchemaNotSpecifiedError(QueryCompilationErrors.scala:1007)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$getOrInferFileFormatSchema$12(DataSource.scala:212)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:212)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:411)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:228)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:185)
  ... 47 elided

scala> spark.read.format("orc").schema("id int").load("/tmp/data").count
res18: Long = 0

scala> spark.read.format("orc").schema("id int").load("/tmp/data/a","/tmp/data/b","/tmp/data/c").count
res19: Long = 33
```

Comment: For this example, would `load('/tmp/data/')` also work? Or would it require nested folders like `path=a`, `path=b` for partitions?

Comment: `load('/tmp/data/')` this may not work.. tested & added code with results in above. in case of partitions it works in different way.